# IONIC 3 'at' does not exist in type 'ILocalNotification

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, localnotification

I want  show notification at fix time 10 AM every day

```
var today = new Date();
     var tomorrow = new Date();
     tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate());
     tomorrow.setHours(19);
     tomorrow.setMinutes(36);
     tomorrow.setSeconds(0);
     var tomorrow_at_9_am = new Date(tomorrow);

     this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'test',
      text: 'découvrez nous actuailité du jour',
      icon: "ic_notifications",
      at: tomorrow_at_9_am,
      every:'day'
                                      });
```

this is the error that i get :

```
  Argument of type '{ id: number; title: string; text: string; icon: string; 
     at: Date; every: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 
     'ILocalNotification | ILocalNotification[]'. Object literal may only
     specify known properties, and 'at' does not exist in type 'ILocalNotification | ILocalNotification[]'.
      L82:  icon: "ic_notifications",
      L83:  at: tomorrow_at_9_am,
      L84:  every:'day'
```

Have I stuck 3 days ago with this problem any help?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, `ILocalNotification` doesn't have an `at` property.

Comment: but how can i trigger a notification every day at  specific time ?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it something like:

```
trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},
```

You should have a `trigger` key that receives an object that has an `at` key.

According to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/).

```
// Schedule delayed notification
this.localNotifications.schedule({
   text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
   trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},
   led: 'FF0000',
   sound: null
});
```

Comment: this code won't trigger every day at a specific time, any help please ?

Comment: This is an example of how to use the 'at', that is what you was doing wrong. How this will work is another issue.